# Set variable according to what another variable says

Tags: java, reflection

This is hard to explain so here it is with code:

```
int theVariable;
setVariable(theVariable, 10);

void setVariable(variableName, variableContents){
  variableName.setValue(variableContents);
}
```

I am making a library for settings and when I call `addTextField()` I want to be able to pass a variable name so when you change the text field, that variable is auto-set. I was thinking reflection, but I am not sure if that is the way to go.

Comment: There are a couple of things about your code that would not work -- you are calling a method on an int, and int variables are not objects and so cannot have methods called on them.  But also you are passing the int to a method and then attempting to change that int's value, and that isn't possible either.  Java doesn't pass a reference to that int, it passes the int's value.  You can pass some object reference to the method and call a method on the object, but I actually like the "Map of String variable names to their values" from Kevin that's been given.

Comment: @arcy I didn't mean for it to appear I was trying to run methods on int. I was showing how you could hypothetically set the value based on variable name.

Comment: One gets all kinds of people at all kinds of levels of knowledge about programming here, so one cannot assume that a poster knows that calling a method on an int won't work.  One thing about putting code into a question, especially code that is syntactically correct for a given language: we readers tend to look at it as actual code, not pseudo-code.  Anyway, glad you got your question answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Map of String variable names to their values:

```
Map<String, Integer> variableMap = new HashMap<>();

void setVariable(String variableName, int variableContents){
  variableMap.put(variableName, variableContents);
}

public Integer getVariable(String variableName){
   return variableMap.get(variableName);
}
```

Obviously you can expand on this quite a bit with generics and error checking, but this is the basic approach.